# Laplace's equation or common 2nd order PDE?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Is it correct to say that equation

$$ u_{xx} +u_{yy}=0 $$

has as solution $ u(x,y)=\Phi_1(y+ix) + \Phi_2(y-ix) $ ?

I am not intended to solve it with any condition. I just wanted to solve  (via polynomial $\lambda^2 +1 =0$) the pure equation, regardless of physical meaning.
Can solution written be left in this way or is there any other way to express it without involving $i$ constant (like in 2nd order ODEs)? thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proposal is almost correct. In fact, this is a conclusion from complex analysis. The conclusion reads that any real-valued harmonic function (i.e., solution to the Laplace equation) must be the real part (or imaginary part, as per your preference) of a holomorphic function, and vise versa.

The way for its proof more or less follows your idea. Define
\begin{align}
z&=x+iy,\\
\bar{z}&=x-iy.
\end{align}
It is not hard to verify that
$$
\Delta=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2}+\frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2}=4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}.
$$
Therefore,
$$
\Delta u=0\iff\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=0.
$$
However,
$$
\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}=0\iff\frac{\partial}{\partial\bar{z}}\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\right)=0,
$$
which implies that $\partial u/\partial z$ is holomorphic. Thus
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}=g'(z)
$$
for some holomorphic $g$. Integrate this last equation, and one obtains
$$
u(z,\bar{z})=g(z)+\overline{h(z)},
$$
where $h$ is another holomorphic function.

Finally, since $u$ is real valued, it is a must that $h=g+K$ with $K\in\mathbb{R}$. Therefore,
$$
u=\Re\left(2g+K\right),
$$
meaning that $u$ is the real part of some holomorphic function.

Conversely, if $g$ is holomorphic, it is straightforward to check that its real part is a harmonic function:
$$
\Delta\left(\Re\left(g\right)\right)=4\frac{\partial^2}{\partial z\partial\bar{z}}\frac{g(z)+\overline{g(z)}}{2}=0.
$$

Back to the real expression. If $u$ is harmonic, then
$$
u(x,y)=\Re\left(2g(z)\right)=g(z)+\overline{g(z)}=g(x+iy)+\bar{g}(x-iy)
$$
for some holomorphic $g$. Here $\bar{g}$, as a different function from $g$, is defined as
$$
\bar{g}(z)=\overline{g(\bar{z})}.
$$